# Prohibit exchange of personnel sensitive infos in strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to implement a chat functionality that should prohibit exchange of personel informations between the two users.

Let's say the following message : "Hi John, i would like to continue this conversation via phone here goes my number : 06632878 78"

The chat should be able to spot the phone number and hide it to only display:

"Hi John, i would like to continue this conversation via phone here goes my number : (Hidden infos)".

I know the users are gonna eventually, outsmart any kind of system, but where can i start implementing this

I must escape phone numbers, linked links, Facebook twitter whatsapps .....

is there any JS library that can get me up and running ?

Comment: It's *extremely* easy to outsmart this: "call me at zero six six three two eight seven eight seven eight" will immediacy defeat any number checks. If you try to account for that, they can just misspell those slightly. If you try to account for *that* you then start blocking legitimate messages. You end up getting into the territory where people would start seeing "My favourite rapper is (hidden info)pac".

Comment: If you really want to get into this trouble, don't start with phone numbers, they are weird animals, there are loooots of different formats, even if you target one single country. Worldwide support would be a huge mess. Also aking to recommend a library is considered off-topic here